# Getting Instagram feed to my website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, instagram

I am just wondering how to get the Instagram feeds on my website.
I have just tried but if I include the embed code, its only working for that specific feed only.
Here I need is; to get all feeds of my Instagram to my website instead of a specific feed.
Code I tried lies here

```
<blockquote class="instagram-media" data-instgrm-captioned data-instgrm-version="7" style=" background:#FFF; border:0; border-radius:3px; box-shadow:0 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.5),0 1px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.15); margin: 1px; max-width:658px; padding:0; width:99.375%; width:-webkit-calc(100% - 2px); width:calc(100% - 2px);"><div style="padding:8px;"> <div style=" background:#F8F8F8; line-height:0; margin-top:40px; padding:50.0% 0; text-align:center; width:100%;"> <div style=" background:url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACwAAAAsCAMAAAApWqozAAAABGdBTUEAALGPC/xhBQAAAAFzUkdCAK7OHOkAAAAMUExURczMzPf399fX1+bm5mzY9AMAAADiSURBVDjLvZXbEsMgCES5/P8/t9FuRVCRmU73JWlzosgSIIZURCjo/ad+EQJJB4Hv8BFt+IDpQoCx1wjOSBFhh2XssxEIYn3ulI/6MNReE07UIWJEv8UEOWDS88LY97kqyTliJKKtuYBbruAyVh5wOHiXmpi5we58Ek028czwyuQdLKPG1Bkb4NnM+VeAnfHqn1k4+GPT6uGQcvu2h2OVuIf/gWUFyy8OWEpdyZSa3aVCqpVoVvzZZ2VTnn2wU8qzVjDDetO90GSy9mVLqtgYSy231MxrY6I2gGqjrTY0L8fxCxfCBbhWrsYYAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC); display:block; height:44px; margin:0 auto -44px; position:relative; top:-22px; width:44px;"></div></div> <p style=" margin:8px 0 0 0; padding:0 4px;"> <a href="https://www.instagram.com/p/BGUbA_UyBCl/" style=" color:#000; font-family:Arial,sans-serif; font-size:14px; font-style:normal; font-weight:normal; line-height:17px; text-decoration:none; word-wrap:break-word;" target="_blank">It&#39;s national #gardening #exercise day! Yes, seriously. Get moving and pick up some Class A #organic #compost from #RIRRC! #gardener #gardenlove #gardenlife #bloom</a></p> <p style=" color:#c9c8cd; font-family:Arial,sans-serif; font-size:14px; line-height:17px; margin-bottom:0; margin-top:8px; overflow:hidden; padding:8px 0 7px; text-align:center; text-overflow:ellipsis; white-space:nowrap;">A photo posted by Rhode Island Resource Recovery (@rirrc) on <time style=" font-family:Arial,sans-serif; font-size:14px; line-height:17px;" datetime="2016-06-06T16:05:29+00:00">Jun 6, 2016 at 9:05am PDT</time></p></div></blockquote>
```

Can any one suggest me how could i achieve this?

Comment: Honestly I don't understand what your html does but you can look into instafeed

Comment: It is the embed code,  but works only for that specific feed

Comment: First, your code is not a feed. It's a code to embed a specific image into a page, that could be easily replaced by a <img src=""> tag. So, it will only embed a specific image (not a feed). As Dmitri Tsoy said above, try instafeed.js ( google it ).

Comment: Ya..its not a feed..its just an embed code of a specific image.I want toknow if can add all feeds anyway

Comment: http://instafeedjs.com/ <- You have all the instructions there.

Answer (score 0):

First thing is, you are trying to embed a single post not a complete feed. There are a number of plugins like Instafeedjs.com to get the feed on your website. If you are looking for a custom code to embed Instagram feed on your website then here are the steps you need to follow. You can also go through this post for detailed steps. - [Embedding Instagram feed in your website](http://www.logicalfeed.com/posts/1171/Embedding-Instagram-feed-in-your-website)

**1. Get Access Token from Instagram Developer site:** Logon to Instagram developer network and register as new client. Once done you will receive a Client Id and Client Secret. Use these two and get the Access Token.

**2. Call Instagram API using Access Token to get recent feed:** For testing you can just try the URL with access token in a browser and check the response. Later you can make this call from any of your server side scripting language by making simple HTTP GET request.

**Source:** - [Steps to Embed Instagram feed in your website](http://www.logicalfeed.com/posts/1171/Embedding-Instagram-feed-in-your-website)

Comment: Hi, could you please specify how to get the access token from those 2 client id and secret, I havent been able to find it. could you also explain how it looks the url on your second step? instagram.com/access_token ???

Comment: Use this URL to get the access token. Substitute your client ID and redirect values to get the access token->  https://www.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=PUT_YOUR_CLIENT_ID_HERE&redirect_uri=YOUR_REDIRECT_URL&response_type=token